# MongoDB uses Dynamic Port?

Tags: mongodb

We're using a MongoDB replica on Windows using default ports (27017).

Our servers are all behind firewalls and we want to configure the firewall to only allow the default port open.

However, when looking at netstat, we see the following ports used:

```
[mongod.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:27017          SERVER-NAME:0           LISTENING
[mongod.exe]
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          SERVER-NAME:0           LISTENING
```

Why is mongo suing the dynamic port 47001? we had to open the dynamic port on the firewall (in addition to the default 27017) to allow other servers to access it.

Why does mongo need the dynamic port? can I at least force it to use a preconfigured port?

Thanks!

Comment: Are these servers a replica-set and/or a shared cluster?

Comment: only replica-set, however they also host the actual application which does queries and updates.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how we can see that the default port is being used for the `mongo` instances, the port has to come from either the `shardsvr` or `configsvr` runtimes.

Judging by the comments...
Your best bet is to check if the ports are being used by the replica set.

```
db.runCommand( { replSetGetStatus : 1 } )
```

The port used should show up in the `name` part of the output document.

Comment: The name is SERVER-NAME:defaultport, and doesn't have any information on the dynamic port used.